# Apply a filter over an image with a brush

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gpuimage

I am working with [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) on an image editor application.

I would like to apply filters on a brush stroke area, like Snapseed does:

[image]

1) Can it be done with GPUImage? I can't find any reference about it. I see that `GPUImageFilter` has a method `setPoint:forUniformName:` but I don't know what it is for. I have tried it but couldn't get it to work.

2) If this can't be done with GPUImage, I would very much appreciate if someone can tell me how to do it and point me in the right direction.

Thanks